# Safari 11 text center & letter spacing issue

Tags: css, safari

I have the following problem which occured in Safari 11. Safari browser does not "repaint" or "recalculate" the position of the text correctly when the styles are placed before closing `body` tag.
These styles causing the issue:

```css
h1 {
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You could see the example here. The text will repositon when you click on it in Safari. Is there any workaround to position text correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/rauot9tq/3/
or:
http://jsfiddle.net/rauot9tq/4/

In the picture below, there is misplaced text in the first line and doubled when clicked on it in the second line:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this issue is to force Safari to re-render the content.
Pure css solution is e.g. to set styles in `<head>` element to:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

and in the footer:

```
body {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rauot9tq/10/

---

Another soulution could be to force Safari to redraw using JS:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('body').offsetWidth;
document.querySelector('body').style.display = 'block';
```

fiddle with JS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rauot9tq/11/

Answer (score 0):

I've just came across the same issue and it looks like this yours is the only jsfiddle available with simple and proper reproduction, thank you. Though I think the cause of the issue isn't `<style>` before `</body>`, otherwise simple `<span>` inserted in between those two could fix the problem. I was able to solve the problem changing text container `display` property to `inline-block`, and adding `width` to it, so my text could still be in the center.

```
h1 {
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rauot9tq/28/ .